# Where is Grandpa going next? A Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> First Grandpa goes to Biloxi in China
>
> Then he goes to Del Norte in Spain
>
> Then he goes to Manchester in France
>
> Then he goes to Sydney in ________?

Fill in the blank and tell me why.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

He goes to Sydney in

> Denmark

Like Bass said :

> It could be Finland, Sweden or Norway so I might be wrong

Because

> the names of the places contain the cardinal direction in the language of the country. So Bilo**xi** contains West in Chinese. Del **Norte** contains North in Spanish. Manch**est**er contains East in French. And **Syd**ney contains South in Danish.

Comment: By that logic alone, Sydney could also be in Sweden or Norway. (Or conceivably even in Finland.) Can't figure out a way to narrow it down any more than that, though.

Comment: I didn't know it was the same in Swedish,Finnish and Norwegian :/. I just used google translate language detector on `syd`.

Comment: In Finnish, it isn't; Swedish is an official language of Finland though. Come to think of it now, I'm pretty much convinced that this very puzzle is the sole purpose why [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syd) lists the words in such a bizarrely unreadable way, with all the languages on the same page :-)

Comment: Based on these, then certainly *language* tag is applicable.